# Adding product search backend to ML Kit showcase

Tags: android, object-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm trying to add my own search backend to Google's ML Kit template.

In SearchEngine.kt I've added this

```
companion object {

    private const val TAG = "SearchEngine"
    var url = "JSON URL"

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    private fun createRequest(searchingObject: DetectedObjectInfo): JsonObjectRequest {
        val objectImageData = searchingObject.imageData
            ?: throw Exception("Failed to get object image data!")

        // Hooks up with your own product search backend here.
        // My added code
        return JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                { response ->
                    print("JSON request was a success$response")
                },
                { error ->
                    throw Exception("Failed to get product!$error")
                }
        )
    }
}
```

However, I'm still getting just the barcode appearing.

When I barcode is detected, this is ran

LiveBarcodeScanningActivity.kt

```
   workflowModel?.detectedBarcode?.observe(this, Observer { barcode ->
        if (barcode != null) {
            val barcodeFieldList = ArrayList<BarcodeField>()
            barcodeFieldList.add(BarcodeField("Raw Value", barcode.rawValue ?: ""))
            BarcodeResultFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, barcodeFieldList)
        }
    })
```

Do I need to add anything here to make my json request show on screen?

Considering on the gif of the barcode scanner on the [Git](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/mlkit-material-android) it shows a product object that's been searched. Therefore, I'm assuming this can be done quite simply.

Answer (score 1):

Barcode scanning is not hooked up with SearchEngine in the sample app, only Object Detection does.

Instead of display BarcodeResultFragment when a barcode is detected, you can trigger product search and handle response like StaticObjectDetectionActivity does
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/material-showcase/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/md/StaticObjectDetectionActivity.kt#L252

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was looking over the code in the past few days and I noticed SearchEngine isn't attached to BarcodeScanner. Do you think this'll be able to work by copying the relevent functions from StaticObjectDetectionActivity? Or should I make a whole StaticObjectDetectionActivity class within the barcode scanner?

Comment: I think it should work by just copying relevant functions.

Comment: I've pretty much got it to work. Just had to fully understand the whole code. But I should've done that anyway to be honest.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)